# Cannot connect _UserLayout.cshtml to Dashboard in Guest Area

Tags: asp.net-core

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The layout view '/Views/Shared/_UserLayout' could not be located. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Shared/_UserLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `_UserLayout` is located in `Views/Shared/_UserLayout`,you could just using the following code:

```
@{ 
    Layout = "_UserLayout";
}
```

Or specify the whole path(Be sure add `.cshtml`):

```
@{ 
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_UserLayout.cshtml";
}
```

**Note**:This code you could put it in specific Razor View or Razor Pages.Also you could put it in `_ViewStart.cshtml`(`_ViewStart.cshtml` should be placed directly in the `/Pages` (or `/Views`) folder)